# Google_Service_Oauth2 is undefined

Tags: api, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use the google api in order to be able to sign in with google. However, when
I try to create a new Google_Service_Oauth2 object, it shows
'Undifined type 'Google_Service_Oauth2', is there any alternatives for it? is the Google_Service_Oauth2 class replaced with another one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google\_Service\_OAuth2 is 'Undefined type' in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578637/google-service-oauth2-is-undefined-type-in-php)